# Delphi Chromium Embedded (DCEF3) : The procedure entry could not be located in DLL

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, tchromium

I installed the Delphi Chromium Embedded 3 (DCEF3) and it's working.

The problem is, everytime i restart Delphi, i get this error :

'The procedure entry point @CefLib could not be located in the dynamic link library DCEF_D7.bpl'.

I need to remove the package and install again to it work. Then when i exit Delphi and open it again, same error occurs. How to avoid it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure the .Bpl is for D2007 and not D7?  Also, have you tried using TDump.Exe (in Delphi's Bin folder) on DCEF_D7.Bpl to check whether the error msg is accurate?

Comment: @MartynA There is no package for D2007, so i use the Delphi 7's pakcage.

Comment: I don't use DCEF3 myself, but usually component libraries have one or more design-time packages and, usually, one or more run-time ones, and you should have a BPL file and a DPK file for each.  Have you recompiled all the DPK files and (if necessary) moved the resulting BPLs to somewhere on your system path?

Comment: @MartynA This component use a lot of DLLs ; these DLLs are in the Library path of Delphi, but no on the %path% environment variable. Could be this the cause ?

Comment: Could be.  My guess would be that an incorrect version of one of the DLLs/BPLs is being loaded instead of the correct one.  You haven't answered either of my queries, so the best I can suggest is that you try debugging your problem by the technique of tracing the execution of a second instance of the IDE as it loads the library's packages.

Comment: @MartynA Will do the tests you suggest and get back. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the dll's in your environment path or in Delphi add the path to the dll's in Delphi -> Tools -> Environment Options -> Library - > Library Path.

if that still doesn't work try adding to the Browsing path
Delphi -> Tools -> Environment Options -> Library - > Browsing Path.